# How to package Image and other assets with a SugarCRM Module?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am very new (a week) into learning and developing with SugarCRM.

I am working on a set of modules, 3 of them that all work together for a custom Project system.  I need to package a set of about 30 images with my extensions though.

What is the best way to package images or any asset for that matter be it css, javascript,  images?

Should I simply save them under a folder in my module and link to them at that location?  `/custom/modules/moduleNameHere/images/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted norm is to put them in custom/themes/default/images but your way is good too if these images will never be theme altered.